# DynamoDB Local with docker-compose not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run docker-compose with rabbit and dynamodb local
When I run dynamodb local by command line it works fine, the command that I use is:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 --name=dynamodb -v D:/volumes/dynamodb:/data/ -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=root -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=pass -e AWS_REGION=us-east-1 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /data
```

But when I try to run with docker compose I get the following error:

```
λ docker logs dynamodb
Unrecognized option: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /data
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried the command like:

- -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /data
- java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /data
- -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath .data
- java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath .data

But, when I run with "java" in the begginning the error is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath
```

I tried differente ways to use volume and with version 2, but none worked

I tried to do what's described in:

- [How to fix dynamodb local call using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691892/how-to-fix-dynamodb-local-call-using-docker-compose)
- https://github.com/ykrevnyi/docker-dynamodb-local/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
- [How to fix dynamodb local call using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691892/how-to-fix-dynamodb-local-call-using-docker-compose)
- [How to persist data in a dockerized DynamoDB using volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852473/how-to-persist-data-in-a-dockerized-dynamodb-using-volumes)

I'm using docker (not toolbox) and Win10
My docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3"

  services:

    rabbit:
      container_name: rabbitmq
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "node_health_check"]
        interval: 2s
        timeout: 3s
        retries: 30

    dynamodb:
      container_name: dynamodb
      image: amazon/dynamodb-local:latest
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      volumes:
        - ./volumes/dynamodb:/data/
      environment:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: root
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: pass
        AWS_REGION: us-east-1
      command: ["java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"]
```

Comment: This no longer works. I have tried for hours to do exactly what you want and only docker run works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either write your command in the exec form (i.e. as a list of elements) or in the shell form (i.e. as a single string) but you cannot mix both... or you get the error you just had. Choose either of the following

```
command: "java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
command: ["java", "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-sharedDb", "-dbPath", "./data"]
```

Reference: [CMD instruction for Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)